# How to update one2many in customers from accounting invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I have created an one2many to customer form. So, when I am validating (button validate) an invoice I am trying to pass some values in that one2many. I have tried many ways and followed odoo forums, but I am having trouble to do that. Using following code:
My one2many field is 'customer_status' in 'res.partner' :

```
@api.multi

@api.model

def invoice_validate(self):

customer_obj=self.env['res.partner']

customer_id=customer_obj.search([('id','=',self.partner_id.id)])

customer_line=customer_obj.browse(customer_id)

dd = {'policy_number': self.policy_no,}

customer_stat_add = customer_obj.write([customer_line.id],{

'customer_status': [(0, 0, dd)]

})

state_change = self.write({'state': 'open'})

return state_change, customer_stat_add
```

It gives me this error:

```
ValueError: "invoice_validate() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" while evaluating
u'invoice_validate()'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

buttons w/ new api need `@api.multi` and if you want to work on a single object you can use `self.ensure_one()`;

```
@api.multi
def foo(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    print self.my_field
```

Also, you don't need to browse object as you already get browse objects w/ new api.

Bear in mind that if that feature is an odoo base feature you must call super().method_name to not break anything ;)